# Dxl view move objects

Tags: ibm-doors

Can you move an entire object from one view to another (without deleting it in one view, load another view, create object in the new view and populate it ? If yes, can you tell me how or point me in the right direction? And also, how can i get the information from the last column, without needing to iterate though all the columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a bit more precise in your wording, it is unclear what you want.
In DOORS, a Module contains objects. The structure of the module determines  which attributes each object has. Views are a, well, a view on these objects. A view determines which attributes of the object are shown, these are the columns shown in a view. Additionally, a view can have a filter, which determines which objects of the module are shown.

So, to answer your question, if one view of a module contains an object and another view of the same module does not show that object, you need to adopt the filter of the other view.

Your second question is about DXL, right? No, I do not know of a function that tells you the number of columns in a view, so that you can use the `column (index)` function to get the last column, but a small loop

```
Column cLast
for cLast in m do {}
// now cLast contains the last column of the current view
```

should not hurt. But are you sure that you really want to work with columns? Usually, scripts rather deal with attributes of objects, and only rarely with columns (the exception being dxl layout columns and of course scripts that manipulate views).

Update: to add to my comment about filters in views, there actually is a way of adding single objects to a view, i.e. the accept/reject method. You could have a script like

```
Object o
for o in entire current Module do {
    reject o
    if intOf(o."Absolute Number""") == 10 then accept o 
    if intOf(o."Absolute Number""") > 20 then accept o
    if o."Requrement type""" == "Functional" then accept o
}
filtering on
```

but this addition will be very short-lived: as soon as you change the view, it forgets that sort of filtering, even if you save the view. So, again, it is not a move.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, you are right about the second part, i was refering to attributes also but i was thinking in an sql fashion when i asked about columns, sorry. As for the first question, i will try to rephrase it. What is the optimal way of moving one object from a view to another view?

Comment: If you are really talking about views and not modules, then there is no real "move", you only have an excerpt of which objects you show at this moment.  When you load two different views in one single module and they show a different set of objects, go to Tools -> Filter -> Define for each view.There you might see that one view shows e.g. only objects with requirement type "Functional", another view might only show objects that have "Safety Related" set to "true" . In this case, you would have to change the object's properties so that it appears in another view. it all depends on your filters.

Comment: I have the following scenario: I try to attach your script ( the one from the update comment ) to a attribute and when i go Tools -> refresh DXL attributes i get error and doors closes - i tried with a basic if and i didnt had any problems,  but when i include filtering on in the script it crashes (why). How can I attach a script to a module and run it when i refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the comment on using the second script in a DXL attribute:
DXL attributes do not work this way.

1. in a DXL attribute you would never have a loop over all objects, you only refer to a single object and you calculate a value for this object's attribute.
2. accept and reject work on views, DXL attributes have a content, these are different concepts.

If you want to use DXL attributes, you might have one of type boolean and use a script like

```
bool showMe=false
// in DXL Attributes, obj contains the currently evaluated object (not the "current" object!)
if intOf(obj."Absolute Number""") == 10 then showMe=true
if intOf(obj."Absolute Number""") > 20 then showMe=true
// the name of the DXL Attribute is stored automatically in the variable attrDXLName
obj.attrDXLName = showMe
```

and then you have a view with a filter that shows only these objects where the attribute's value is "true"